# Updating dataframe on values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to update data frame X on values from dataframe from Y.

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'],
                  'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2'], 
                  'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2'], 
                  'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2']})

    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2

Y = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1'],
                  'B': ['B0', 'B1'], 
                  'C': ['C0xx', 'C1xx'], 
                  'D': ['D0xx', 'D1xx']})

    A   B     C     D
0  A0  B0  C0xx  D0xx
1  A1  B1  C1xx  D1xx
```

And the result to be:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0xx  D0xx
1  A1  B1  C1xx  D1xx
2  A2  B2  C2    D2
```

Of course my dataframe is match bigger.

Comment: What is output if `Y = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1'],
                  'B': ['B0', 'B1'], 
                  'C': ['C0xx', 'C1xx'], 
                  'D': ['D0xx', 'D1xx']}, index=[2,1])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) if need add missing values by `A, B` columns in both `df`:

```
print (Y.set_index(['A','B']).combine_first(X.set_index(['A','B'])).reset_index())

    A   B     C     D
0  A0  B0  C0xx  D0xx
1  A1  B1  C1xx  D1xx
2  A2  B2    C2    D2
```

Unfortunately `update` works bad:

```
Y = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1'],
                  'B': ['B0', 'B1'], 
                  'C': ['C0xx', 'C1xx'], 
                  'D': ['D0xx', 'D1xx']}, index=[2,1])
print (X)
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2

print (Y)
    A   B     C     D
2  A0  B0  C0xx  D0xx
1  A1  B1  C1xx  D1xx

X.update(Y)
print (X)
    A   B     C     D
0  A0  B0    C0    D0
1  A1  B1  C1xx  D1xx
2  A0  B0  C0xx  D0xx
```

---

```
X.set_index(['A','B']).update(Y.set_index(['A','B']))
print (X)
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
```

---

```
print (Y.set_index(['A','B']).combine_first(X.set_index(['A','B'])).reset_index())
    A   B     C     D
0  A0  B0  C0xx  D0xx
1  A1  B1  C1xx  D1xx
2  A2  B2    C2    D2
```

Comment: Glad can help! Good luck and nice day!

Answer (score 3):

## 1. Both DataFrames have the same index

This is the case you presented in the example given in your question.
You might want to use the `update` method:

```
>>> X.update(Y)
>>> X

    A   B     C     D
0  A0  B0  C0xx  D0xx
1  A1  B1  C1xx  D1xx
2  A2  B2    C2    D2
```

It also works if lines are in a different order in X and Y:

```
>>> Y = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A1', 'A0'], 
                      'B': ['B1', 'B0'], 
                      'C': ['C1xx', 'C0xx'], 
                      'D': ['D1xx', 'D0xx']}, 
                     index=[1,0])
>>> Y
    A   B     C     D
1  A1  B1  C1xx  D1xx
0  A0  B0  C0xx  D0xx

>>> X.update(Y)
>>> X
    A   B     C     D
0  A0  B0  C0xx  D0xx
1  A1  B1  C1xx  D1xx
2  A2  B2    C2    D2
```

## 2. Different indexes

If Y has a different index:

```
>>> Y = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1'], 
                      'B': ['B0', 'B1'], 
                      'C': ['C0xx', 'C1xx'], 
                      'D': ['D0xx', 'D1xx']}, 
                     index=[2,1])
>>> Y

    A   B     C     D
2  A0  B0  C0xx  D0xx
1  A1  B1  C1xx  D1xx
```

You can still use `update` if you can find another column usable as an index (identifying the lines so that they match the lines to be replaced). I take the example of the "A" column but a multiple index would work as well.

```
>>> X2, Y2 = X.set_index("A"), Y.set_index("A")
>>> X2.update(Y2)
>>> X2.reset_index(inplace=True)
>>> X2
    A   B     C     D
0  A0  B0  C0xx  D0xx
1  A1  B1  C1xx  D1xx
2  A2  B2    C2    D2
```

Comment: Very neat answer!

Comment: It works only because first rows in both dataframes have same index, what in real data is not possible. Check my edit.

Comment: @jezrael Thank you for your remark, I added your example in my answer. If possible, using a different index works fine.